# How does forEach() method works in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I am writing a snippet:

```
List<Integer> list=Arrays.toList(2,4,6,8);
list.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Please explain me the flow of method call in the above snippet. How the forEach() method is passing the parameters to the accept() method? Does the forEach() method calls the accept method each time? 
Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
i-> System.out.println(i)
```

returns an object of Consumer interface. forEach() calls the accept() method of that object with i as the parameter.

Comment: What is this `accept()` method you speak of?

Comment: It is the only abstract method of functional Interface "Consumer".

Comment: @azurefrog: [This one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-).

Comment: Why don't you look at the javadoc and/or source?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the gist of your question.  I thought you were asking about looping, but you're trying to get at how lambdas work.

Comment: I know how lambdas work. But I am confused which method is invoked first. Is it the "forEach()" or the "accept ()" because both of them are working togather!

Comment: The code `List<String> list=Arrays.toList(2,4,6,8);` should be `List<Integer> list=Arrays.toList(2,4,6,8);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [`Consumer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) is a [*functional interface*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html), your lambda function can implicitly satisfy it. So when you do

```
list.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

what you're doing *conceptually* (more below) is

```
list.forEach(new Consumer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(String i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
});
```

The instance is then passed into `forEach`, which calls its `accept` method for each entry in the list.

From a comment you made on the question:

> I am confused which method is invoked first. Is it the "forEach()" or the "accept ()" because both of them are working togather!

The order of things is:

- An instance of the anonymous class is created *(in effect, via the `invokedynamic` operation)*
- `forEach` is called, passing in that reference
- `forEach`'s code *calls* `accept` repeatedly, each time passing one of the list items into it (which it receives as `i`)

Note I said **conceptually**. An anonymous class isn't really created by the compiler; instead, a new bytecode operation called `invokedynamic` is used to create the consumer instance.

Comment: The `list.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));` can also be written using method reference as `list.forEach(System.out::println);`. Also, the entire code can be just: `Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8).forEach(System.out::println); `